# NFS mount hanging when mounted from fstab (Ubuntu 18)

Tags: nfs, ubuntu-18.04

I'm setting up an NFS mount on some Ubuntu 18 servers, following [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-18-04).

I have followed all of the instructions and it works when (on a remote) I run

```
mount 10.0.0.7:/mnt/nfs_share /mnt/nfs_share
```

In the `/etc/fstab` file for the remote servers that are to be mounting the share, I have tried various options and ended up with the following line:

```
10.0.0.7:/mnt/nfs_share /mnt/nfs_share nfs defaults,tcp,_netdev 0 0
```

When I boot, it does not mount.

Here's the weird part. After booting, I check to see if it mounted and find out it didn't. If I type `mount /mnt/nfs_share`, it hangs. If I type `mount 10.0.0.7:/mnt/nfs_share /mnt/nfs_share` followed by `umount /mnt/nfs_share` followed by `mount /mnt/nfs_share`, it works fine.

Even weirder, if I type `mount /mnt/nfs_share`, it hangs. If I then remove it from /etc/fstab, and try again it says not found. Then if I re-add it and type `mount /mnt/nfs_share`, it works.

What am I missing?